# How do I get iTunes to use the media keys?

Tags: itunes, media-keys

I've tried for a long time to get the media keys on my keyboard to work with iTunes. They work just fine in winamp (2.95!) but they only work in iTunes when the iTunes window is focused. Anyone know how to get them to work all the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This blog](http://andy.hillhome.org/blog/code/ituneskeys/) post is about a couple of apps this guy wrote to solve this problem. Download link at the bottom of the page (though I recommend you read the whole post).

Comment: awesome. worked great! Wish it didn't add an icon to the system tray, but I can live with that.

Comment: Glad it worked :)